# How can I split a string into an array using both "\\" or "/" as a separator (i.e. in a single regex) in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, regex, string

I'm attempting to split any arbitrary filepath such as:

`"c:\\directory\\another_directory\\filename.ext"` (Windows OS)

**OR**

`"c:/directory/another_directory/filename.ext"` (UNIX)

into an array, separated by either "\\" or "/" (depending on the operating system in which filepath strings are being read).

The desired output is an array such as:

```
['c:', 'directory', 'another_directory', 'filename.txt']
```

What is a regular expression I can use in a split method such as:

`str.split(new RegExp(/(\\|/)/i))` *(invalid regex)*

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `.match`, and match characters which are neither slashes nor backslashes:

```js
const doSplit = str => str.match(/[^/\\]+/g);

console.log(doSplit(String.raw`c:\\directory\\another_directory\\filename.ext`));
console.log(doSplit("c:/directory/another_directory/filename.ext"));
```

Comment: That works, but `str.split(/[/\\]/)` seems more straightforward to me.

Comment: @CertainPerformance Thank you! Do you see any issues with using a character set in a split method such as `str.split(/[/\\]+/g)`? Is there any specific reason to not use split here? I prefer the idea of matching separators instead of finding the strings that do not match. Thank you again!

Comment: @mepley Sure, you can split on the slashes instead of matching non-slashes if you want. It doesn't make a difference (unless there can be a leading or trailing slash, which would be a problem with `split` - you'd have to filter out empty strings later).

Comment: @CertainPerformance Good point about the leading or trailing slashes. This won't be an issue in my case, because I can rely on the strings being in the format I mentioned above, but that's a good consideration if you potentially had a string such as `C:/directory/` and went to split the path and take the last element as the folder name.